# Do you know a way to convert CopyBook to XSD in Java?

Tags: java, xsd, copybook

I'm trying to do it quickly with java - get CopyBook file, 
and generate xsd from this CopyBook.

(I know there are some open source projects to create xml from cb, 
but unfortunately, thay generate xml with items and lot of tags and attributes, and it's not XSD as 
well, unfortunately)

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This might fullfill your requirments:-
[cobol to xml convertor](http://cb2xml.sourceforge.net/)

No personal experience with this tool though.

Answer (score 0):

There is no open source, Java based project, that will do this for you, as far as I know. If you need to do this on a recurrent basis, then the solution would be for you to write some Java code to generate an XSD from the metadata you've collected with the XML (there's a good SourceForge cb2xml project, if I recall).

If this is for just one time, then I suggest you download the eval version of [QTAssistant](http://paschidev.com) (I am associated with it); there's a COBOL to XML Schema tool which will do it for you (under the Tools tab, the Enterprise Toolbox group).

There may be a couple of things that could require tweaking your COBOL copybook, depending on how you've got it - nothing different than what you would need to do when using a tool like IBM's Rational Application Developer and such to generate Java beans from a COBOL copybook.

If you get stuck, please send an email to the support address on the site.